# Spring MVC using hibernate Sequence doesn't exist

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

UserBean Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class UserBean {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "AGE")
    private int age;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * @param email the email to set
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     * @return the age
     */
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    /**
     * @param age the age to set
     */
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("UserBean [id=").append(id).append(", name=")
                .append(name).append(", email=").append(email).append(", age=")
                .append(age).append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

I am getting  **ORA:02289 Sequence doesn't exist**

Here is hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="com.abc.bean.UserBean" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Dispatcher package scan

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.dao.impl" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

I have tried the same thing in another laptop and it worked, what is causing the problem? Earlier, I tried to generate a sequence but it didn't worked well

Sql command executed:
`create table users(id int primary key,name varchar(20),email varchar(20),age int);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hibernate use sequence for oracle db if you use GenerationType.AUTO (default global sequence name `hibernate_sequence`) . You should create sequence and configure it in entity mapping , like :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name="user_generator", sequenceName = "user_seq")
@Column(name="ID",allocationSize = 1)
private Integer id;
```

Comment: I tried this but didn't work same error but in another laptop i did the same thing still it is working

Comment: another laptop have another oracle instance it doesn't has to do with anything with oracle instance different same above thing i did in both but only one worked

Comment: for working version you might have sequence and hibernate apply it . for not working version you don't have this sequence

Comment: For working and non working version i don't have sequence

Comment: I have added hibernate_sequence and have not mentioned anywhere in my program to use one but it worked

Comment: it'd default sequence that hibernate is used. this sequence be applyed for all tables whery you use don't specify sequence  and use GenerationType.AUTO

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Oracle you using? As per my knowledge Auto increment not supported in 11g but supports in 12c..

Comment: I am using 11g but I have same version in both laptops still one is working fine while other fails to do
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.AUTO)

I guess this will do the work